# Is an M.2 SSD, secured with a screw, supposed to be snug or loose?

Tags: ssd, m.2

We're mounting some M.2 SSD's on these [delock pci-e > M.2 extender cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn2CJ.jpg) that plug into PCI-e. With the supplied screws from delock the M.2 SSD, when mounted correctly otherwise, is loose, you can move it up and down and a bit sideways.

So, the supplied screw seems too long on first glance. However, someone suggested it might be on purpose to facilitate thermal expansion of the M.2 which sounds reasonable as well.

Should a mounted M.2 be loose or shouldn't it? Would it be advisable to source a shorter screw or plastic washer?

[image: delock pci-e > M.2 extender cards]

Comment: A SSD generates almost no heat.  It's designed to be secured when it's installed.

Comment: The picture you linked to shows a screw completely inserted into the threaded support - does the screw go in completely without the SSD in place? It could be that the supplied screws are too long or there is something preventing them going in properly. I think a plastic washer would be the nicest solution if the screws are too long - it would give some slight protection to the PCB.

Comment: @andrew-morton It is, isn't it? Didn't even notice that. No, the screw supplied with the card was in a separate pouch, not in the support, which was empty. And no, without SSD the screw won't go in fully either, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it if it's "to long" they likely supplied a single screw that's fits all known SSD m.2 products or depending on the price simply didn't care about the length.